# Markdown in-file links aren't converted

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am setting up and configuring my very first set of Github Pages using Markdown and Jekyll.  All my content has been converted to Markdown, and the basic look and feel of the generated web pages is correct, but there are some significant glitches.  For example, Markdown says within-same-file links should look like `[Link Name](#headername)` in Markdown, but these just show up as literal text in my html output.  For example this line:

```
For more information, see [More About Arrays](#More About Arrays)
```

displays exactly the same (with brackets, parentheses, etc).

Links of the form `[Link Name](some_url)` do work though.

Here's my `_config.yml`:

```
name: RTcmix
markdown: GFM
kramdown:
    syntax_highlighter: rouge
    input: GFM
```

This Github-pages site is mine and not referenced by anybody yet, and so I test by pushing the changes directly to master and wait a while, then view. I have a verified email and I get no error reports.

Comment: Are you running Jekyll locally to see how it renders before publishing? Which rendering engine are you using? You should post some of the markdown code that's not converting correctly. https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/setting-a-markdown-processor-for-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll

Comment: Please see my updated question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links

> Markdown applications don’t agree on how to handle spaces in the middle of a URL. For compatibility, try to URL encode any spaces with %20. Alternatively, if your Markdown application supports HTML, you could use the `a` HTML tag.

The example says to do this:

```
[link](https://www.example.com/my%20great%20page)
```

or

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/my great page">link</a>
```

So your code should be this markdown

```
[More About Arrays](#More%20About%20Arrays)
```

or simply

```
<a href="#More About Arrays">More About Arrays</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  The reformatting of the spaces definitely turns that Markdown link into an html link of the complete form

https://rtcmix.github.io/reference/scorefile/Minc.html#More%20About%20Arrays

but clicking on it does nothing.  The place it is supposed to go is this line:

### More About Arrays

Should my link have *three* hashes to correctly match this?

Comment: The help page for the MacDown app has one Markdown example of an internal link, and it uses a much more "formal" way of naming the target:

## <a name="markdown-pane"></a>The Markdown Preference Pane

Does this mean I need a target like:

### <a name="More About Arrays"></a>More About Arrays

?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adrian for the space-formatting help.  I came up with the following through trial-and-error and looking at the single example in the "Macdown" app's help file.

One working solution is:

1. The target for the link should have the following form with a 'name' tag:

```
### <a name="more-about-arrays"></a>More About Arrays
```

2. The internal link to it should have the form as in this example:

```
For more information, see [More About Arrays](#more-about-arrays) below.
```

In addition, by using a 'name' with no spaces, I remove the need for '%20' formatting because the visible name is not used for navigation and can be left unformatted.